# Retrofit GET method returns HTTP Code 400 even service works on Postman

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am developing an app that shows JSON values on android. I wrote a WCF service that returns JSON Array.

I tried to test my web service on Postman and it returned the values. But i couldn't get any values on an app. I debugged app and showing URL is valid but still getting HTTP CODE 400

Here is my Interface

```
@GET("ClientControl.svc/GetRecords")
Call<List<Records>> records();
```

And here is my retrofit object.

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
.baseUrl("http://192.168.2.134:62665/") // I tried it to change 10.0.3.2 but same
.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
.build();
```

and here is my calling codes

```
    JsonPlaceholderAPI jsonPlaceholderAPI = retrofit.create(JsonPlaceholderAPI.class);

    Call<List<Records>> call = jsonPlaceholderAPI.records();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Records>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Records>> call, Response<List<Records>> response) {
            if(!response.isSuccessful()){
                System.out.println("CODE : "+response.code());

            } 
        } 
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Records>> call, Throwable t) {
            System.out.println(t.getMessage());
        } 
    });
```

Here is my Logcat
    12-24 04:47:46.852 2665-3191/system_process I/ActivityManager: START u0 
    {cmp=com.example.cemal.login/.ServisFisi} from uid 10060 on display 0

```
--------- beginning of main
12-24 04:47:46.983 6086-6086/com.example.cemal.login 
I/AppCompatViewInflater: app:theme is now deprecated. Please move to using 
android:theme instead.
12-24 04:47:47.235 6086-6086/com.example.cemal.login I/System.out: CODE : 
400
12-24 04:47:47.485 6086-6100/com.example.cemal.login W/EGL_emulation: 
eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
 12-24 04:47:47.485 6086-6100/com.example.cemal.login W/OpenGLRenderer: 
 Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xe9bbf760, error=EGL_SUCCESS
 12-24 04:47:48.855 6086-6086/com.example.cemal.login I/Choreographer: 
 Skipped 70 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main 
 thread.
 12-24 04:47:48.909 2665-2684/system_process I/ActivityManager: Displayed 
 com.example.cemal.login/.ServisFisi: +1s992ms
```

My JSON Response that returns from Web Service.

```
"[{\"KODU\":\"TLP.00000001\",\"ACIKLAMA\":\"ÇEK & SENET\",\"KAPALI_FL\":false,\"TARIH\":\"2018-12-24T12:57:27.711864\",\"TUTAR\":1254.78,\"DURUM\":0},{\"KODU\":\"TLP.00000002\",\"ACIKLAMA\":\"FİNANSMAN\",\"KAPALI_FL\":true,\"TARIH\":\"2018-12-24T07:57:27.711864\",\"TUTAR\":3251.7895,\"DURUM\":0},{\"KODU\":\"TLP.00000003\",\"ACIKLAMA\":\"MUHASEBE\",\"KAPALI_FL\":true,\"TARIH\":\"2018-12-24T10:57:27.711864\",\"TUTAR\":5421.1256,\"DURUM\":1},{\"KODU\":\"TLP.00000004\",\"ACIKLAMA\":\"MASRAF\",\"KAPALI_FL\":true,\"TARIH\":\"2018-12-21T12:57:27.711864\",\"TUTAR\":952.064,\"DURUM\":0},{\"KODU\":\"TLP.00000005\",\"ACIKLAMA\":\"SATINALMA\",\"KAPALI_FL\":false,\"TARIH\":\"2018-12-25T12:57:27.711864\",\"TUTAR\":37.915,\"DURUM\":1},{\"KODU\":\"TLP.00000006\",\"ACIKLAMA\":\"STOK\",\"KAPALI_FL\":false,\"TARIH\":\"2018-12-24T17:57:27.711864\",\"TUTAR\":54.782,\"DURUM\":1}]"
```

And my POJO Class. I generated it on jsonschema2pojo site.

```
@SerializedName("KODU")
@Expose
private String kODU;
@SerializedName("ACIKLAMA")
@Expose
private String aCIKLAMA;
@SerializedName("KAPALI_FL")
@Expose
private boolean kAPALIFL;
@SerializedName("TARIH")
@Expose
private String tARIH;
@SerializedName("TUTAR")
@Expose
private double tUTAR;
@SerializedName("DURUM")
@Expose
private int dURUM;

public String getKODU() {
    return kODU;
}

public void setKODU(String kODU) {
    this.kODU = kODU;
}

public String getACIKLAMA() {
    return aCIKLAMA;
}

public void setACIKLAMA(String aCIKLAMA) {
    this.aCIKLAMA = aCIKLAMA;
}

public boolean isKAPALIFL() {
    return kAPALIFL;
}

public void setKAPALIFL(boolean kAPALIFL) {
    this.kAPALIFL = kAPALIFL;
}

public String getTARIH() {
    return tARIH;
}

public void setTARIH(String tARIH) {
    this.tARIH = tARIH;
}

public double getTUTAR() {
    return tUTAR;
}

public void setTUTAR(double tUTAR) {
    this.tUTAR = tUTAR;
}

public int getDURUM() {
    return dURUM;
}

public void setDURUM(int dURUM) {
    this.dURUM = dURUM;
}
```

HTTP Code has to be valid but it returns 400. I don't know why. I am new on this.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185718/discussion-on-question-by-cemal-celik-retrofit-get-method-returns-http-code-400).

Comment: The 400 Bad Request error is an HTTP status code that means that the request you sent to the website server, often something simple like a request to load a web page, was somehow incorrect or corrupted and the server couldn't understand it.
So please check again what you are sending to json server i.e. in json payload .It is in correct forn or not

Comment: @KartihShah I know what code 400 is. Problem here is , it is working on Postman but it is not working on Android/Retrofit.

Comment: Check your JSON payload again ,it is in correct form or not

Answer (score 0):

Retrofit BaseUrl must not end with `/` you need to add it to your start of api in interface. So your code will change as below

**Creating builder**

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
.baseUrl("http://192.168.2.134:62665") 
.addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
.build();
```

**Defining method call**

```
@GET("/ClientControl.svc/GetRecords")
Call<List<Records>> records();
```

Also make sure url you have provided is reachable from your mobile device.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your comment. It is still same. Gives code 400.

Comment: can you post screenshot of working url from postman? it mostly looks like your url is incorrect.

Comment: go to browser in your phone and type your ipaddress followed by port number you are accessing and check whether browser displays it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. And it says same thing in there btw.

Comment: so your browser also cannot execute your api?

Comment: Yes. But when i replace my ip to localhost like i said it is launching only on postman.

Comment: run ipconfig on your computer and find out what ip it is using, try again with that ip address

Comment: It is still bad request @KaranMer

Comment: try disabling firewall, it might be blocking your connection